# Importing error in react: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I'm having some import errors but i'm not sure why. Here is my coode:

[lib/client.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH8qf.png)

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbcBA.png)

[Hero.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsGmz.png)

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnqtZ.png)

The issue is when import the {client} in the index.js file. Everything works fine.

But when I import {client} in the Hero.jsx i get this error: "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Not sure why. Someone please help :c

I tried changing it from a default export to a named export and I still get the same issue.

Comment: How do you have the "@" alias in your import path configured, and where are the files located in relation to each other in the directory tree? Are you able to get it imported by changing to a relative path to the file?

Comment: I've added a picture of my file structure. As for the @tag, if you use next 14, don't use app layout and don't use default src directory, the imports would look like that for imports that are outside of the folder that is being imported from.

Comment: In a new create next-app project, the "@/*" alias would typically be configured in a jsconfig.js file at the project root (or tsconfig.ts if using Typescript). For example if I try creating one now (choosing not to use the default src dir and app router), I have these contents in jsconfig.js:      

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
       

I don't see that file in your screenshot. If you have one, can you post the contents? if you don't, I wonder if that is part of the issue here.

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots